# What does the `port` property of a ServicePort object _mean_?

Tags: kubernetes

According to https://kubernetes.io/docs/api-reference/v1.8/#serviceport-v1-core , a `ServicePort`'s `port` (integer) is "The port that will be exposed by this service.", but given that it *doesn't* specify the port on which a backend pod will listen (those are `targetPort` and can even be names to be defined by each backend pod) and it *doesn't* really specify the port to which a frontend pod should connect (those are `nodePort` or auto-assigned), I'm confused as to what it *does* specify.

Are load balancers (ingresses?) required to expose the `port` as identified in a service, or can they map it as well?

The examples at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/ don't always include `name`s for the ports even though the spec says that "All ports within a ServiceSpec must have unique names." -- this leads me to assume that a stringified `port` is also the default `name`. Is that right?

The docs for `ServiceSpec` mention that `port` is the "patch merge key" for its `ports` array. Are this and the previous observation about `port` being the default `name` just forensic evidence that `port` existed first but we wish we'd started with `name`? :)

Comment: Is this a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/a/41510604/1105015 ? That is, does that answer clarify that `port` _is_ what a LB has to expose, or is there value to be added by my question and answers to it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between ClusterIP, NodePort and LoadBalancer service types in Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509439/whats-the-difference-between-clusterip-nodeport-and-loadbalancer-service-types)

Comment: @JanosLenart My initial comment mentioned that answer. I think it's only a dup if someone can confirm the role of `port`. We could do that there or here, but i think it's an unanswered sub-question. (That is, i don't care about the rep, I just want the answer and I think others might, too :) )

Comment: Did not notice your first comment, sorry. So, first of all the list of ports (numbers) are exposed on the ClusterIP that is assigned. Even if your service is NodePort of LoadBalancer it will still have a ClusterIP. Second, the same port numbers are exposed on the ExternalIP or LB IP (if these are assigned). Third, if you configure an Ingress object it's `backend:` section will refer to Services. The port there maybe a number but can be a string as well - which will be the port name listed in the Service. Fourth, the name is also interesting for collecting metrics with Prometheus, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The numeric `port` of a `Service`'s `ServicePort` (in its `spec`) is used in the following places:

- The Service is exposed at `spec.clusterIP:spec.ports[*].port` (unless `clusterIP` is set to `"None"`)
- The Service is exposed at `spec.loadBalancerIP:spec.ports[*].port` (if you specify `type: LoadBalancer`)
- It is the *default* value for `targetPort` of that `ServicePort`