# Accessing app on kubernetes using nodeport

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

Dear all I have deployed a sample service such as this:

```
 kubectl get svc
NAME          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes    ClusterIP   10.233.0.1     <none>        443/TCP          1d
mynodejsapp   NodePort    10.233.2.225   <none>        3000:31209/TCP   43s
```

may I ask how do I access the app mynodejsapp on the cluster ip?

When I did a get nodes -o wide this is what I have seen as below,

```
$ kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME                    STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION            EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                  KERNEL-VERSION                   CONTAINER-RUNTIME
controlplane-node-001   Ready     master    2d        v1.9.1+2.1.8.el7   <none>        Oracle Linux Server 7.2   4.1.12-112.14.13.el7uek.x86_64   docker://17.3.1
controlplane-node-002   Ready     master    2d        v1.9.1+2.1.8.el7   <none>        Oracle Linux Server 7.2   4.1.12-112.14.13.el7uek.x86_64   docker://17.3.1
controlplane-node-003   Ready     master    2d        v1.9.1+2.1.8.el7   <none>        Oracle Linux Server 7.2   4.1.12-112.14.13.el7uek.x86_64   docker://17.3.1
default-node-001        Ready     node      2d        v1.9.1+2.1.8.el7   <none>        Oracle Linux Server 7.2   4.1.12-112.14.13.el7uek.x86_64   docker://17.3.1
default-node-002        Ready     node      2d        v1.9.1+2.1.8.el7   <none>        Oracle Linux Server 7.2   4.1.12-112.14.13.el7uek.x86_64   docker://17.3.1
```

Any help. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between ClusterIP, NodePort and LoadBalancer service types in Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509439/whats-the-difference-between-clusterip-nodeport-and-loadbalancer-service-types)

Answer (score 1):

> may i ask how do I access the app mynodejsapp on the cluster ip?

Now, for direct answer to your question in regards to your service overview:

- To access `mynodejsapp` service from **outside** of the cluster you need to target IP of any of the `nodes` on port `31209` (and `kube-proxy` will route it to `mynodejsapp` service for you)
- To access `mynodejsapp` service from **within** the cluster, meaning from another pod running on that same cluster you need to target clusterIP `10.233.2.225:3000` (or alternatively with running `kube-dns` you can use service name directly `mynodejsapp:3000`)

As detailed in [the official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/) clusterIP is tied to service, and in turn it is resolved through kube-dns from service name to clusterIP. In a nutshell you can use clusterIP only from within pods running on said cluster (same as service).

As for exposing services externally through NodePort you can find more info also in [the official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/)

Comment: My nodes a all don't have public IP. Hence I guess I have to do we within the cluster?  Will take a look at the documentation

Comment: Not even your master? How do you access them?

Comment: what is the output of `kubectl get nodes -o wide` in your case? Can you update question with it?

Comment: all external IP is blank for all my nodes and masters

Comment: hm... can you update question with output of `kubectl get nodes -o wide`?