# Kubernetes service ports mapping

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I noticed, and I cannot explain, that some services have

```
NAME      TYPE       CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
web       NodePort   10.104.133.249   <none>        8080:31637/TCP   12m
```

the PORT(S) sections looks like this`8080:31637/TCP`. But this service

```
NAME                            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE    SELECTOR                                                         
grafana                         ClusterIP   10.109.88.206    <none>        80/TCP     84s    app=grafana,release=grafana
```

Only has `80/TCP`. What exactly is the difference between these services? And what exactly does the port `31637` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) abstract way to expose an application running on a set of Pods as a network service. 
With ClusterIP, services are reachable by pods/services in the cluster but cannot accessible from outside network whereas NodePort, exposed a service on a random port between range 30000-32767 which is basically map to port inside your cluster.

In your case `web` service is exposed as type NodePort and you can access it from outside on port 31637 whereas you could not able to access `grafana` service as it is not exposed to outside network.

Check this thread, [What's the difference between ClusterIP, NodePort and LoadBalancer service types in Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509439/whats-the-difference-between-clusterip-nodeport-and-loadbalancer-service-types)  It will help to understand a concept and how it works.