# What is difference between load balancing using Service type ClusterIP and Service type of LoadBalancer?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

When I use Service with type **ClusterIP** and 2 PODS, the traffic is distributed accross the 2 PODs.

I found another Service type **LoadBalancer**. What is the difference between the 2 types of Services? How is **LoadBalancer** different from **ClusterIP** ?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between ClusterIP, NodePort and LoadBalancer service types in Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509439/whats-the-difference-between-clusterip-nodeport-and-loadbalancer-service-types)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ClusterIP** exposes the service on a cluster-internal IP. You cannot access this service from outside the cluster.

**LoadBalancer** assigns an external IP to the service in addition to cluster-internal IP. The external IP can be used to reach the service from outside the cluster. For **LoadBalancer** to work, you need a controller which assigns these external IP. Most cloud providers support LoadBalancer services.

Observe the **TYPE** and **EXTERNAL-IP** columns in the below output. Only LoadBalancer service has an EXTERNAL-IP assigned. This IP can be used to connect to the service from outside the cluster.

```
# kubectl get svc
NAME                                TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)                                                                                                              AGE
jaeger-collector                    ClusterIP      10.111.127.254   <none>         14267/TCP,14268/TCP,9411/TCP                                                                                         36d
jaeger-query                        LoadBalancer   10.106.69.234    10.92.70.150   80:32131/TCP
```