# Unable to access to service from kubernetes master node

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-service, calico

```
[root@kubemaster ~]# kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP             NODE          NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod1deployment-c8b9c74cb-hkxmq   1/1     Running   0          12s   192.168.90.1   kubeworker1   <none>           <none>

[root@kubemaster ~]# kubectl logs pod1deployment-c8b9c74cb-hkxmq
2020/05/16 23:29:56 Server listening on port 8080

[root@kubemaster ~]# kubectl get service -o wide
NAME          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE   SELECTOR
kubernetes    ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP   13m   <none>
pod1service   ClusterIP   10.101.174.159   <none>        80/TCP    16s   creator=sai
```

Curl on master node:

```
[root@kubemaster ~]# curl -m 2 -v -s http://10.101.174.159:80
* About to connect() to 10.101.174.159 port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 10.101.174.159...
* Connection timed out after 2001 milliseconds
* Closing connection 0
```

Curl on worker node 1 is sucessfull for cluster IP ( this is the node where pod is running )

```
[root@kubemaster ~]# ssh kubeworker1 curl -m 2 -v -s http://10.101.174.159:80
Hello, world!
Version: 1.0.0
Hostname: pod1deployment-c8b9c74cb-hkxmq
```

Curl fails on other worker node as well :

```
[root@kubemaster ~]# ssh kubeworker2 curl -m 2 -v -s http://10.101.174.159:80
* About to connect() to 10.101.174.159 port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 10.101.174.159...
* Connection timed out after 2001 milliseconds
* Closing connection 0
```

Comment: could you please try ```curl -m 2 -v -s http://pod1service.default.svc``` from the master node?

Comment: If you're trying to reach a service from outside the cluster proper (even from the console of one of your nodes), would a NodePort service fit your needs better?

Comment: [root@kubemaster ~]# curl -m 2 -v http://pod1service.default.svc
* Could not resolve host: pod1service.default.svc; Unknown error
* Closing connection 0

Comment: David , yes thats true .. but the actual problem we have in set up is "not able to reach cluster ip from with in the cluster"

Comment: David , please clarify this doubt for me .. should the serviceip:port be accessible from inside the pods or also from the k8 nodes ?

Comment: This should be helpful for you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509439/whats-the-difference-between-clusterip-nodeport-and-loadbalancer-service-types).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I was facing the same issue so this is what I did and it worked:**

**Brief:** I am running 2 VMs for a 2 Node cluster. 1 Master Node and 1 Worker Node. A Deployment is running on the worker node. I wanted to curl from the master node so that I can get response from my application running inside a pod on the worker node. For that I deployed a service on the worker node which then exposed those set of pods inside the cluster.

**Issue:** After deploying the service and doing `Kubectl get service`, it provided me with `ClusterIP` of that service and a port (BTW I used `NodePort` instead of Cluster IP when writing the service.yaml). But when curling on that IP address and port it was just hanging and then after sometime giving timeout.

**Solution:** Then I tried to look at the hierarchy. First I need to contact the Node on which service is located then on the port given by the NodePort (i.e The one between 30000-32767) so first I did `Kubectl get nodes -o wide` to get the Internal IP address of the required Node (mine was 10.0.1.4) and then I did `kubectl get service -o wide` to get the port (the one between 30000-32767) and curled it. So my curl command was -> `curl http://10.0.1.4:30669` and I was able to get the output.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should always be using Service DNS instead of Cluster/dynamic IPs to access the application deployed. The service DNS would be **< service-name >.< service-namespace >.svc.cluster.local**, *cluster.local* is the default Kubernetes cluster name, if not changed otherwise.

Now coming to the service accessibility, it may be DNS issues. What you can do is try to check the **kube-dns** pod logs in **kube-system** namespace. Also, try to curl from a standalone pod. If that's working.

`kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 bastion --image=busybox`

`kubectl exec -it bastion bash`

`curl -vvv pod1service.default.svc.cluster.local`

If not the further questions would be, where is the cluster and how it was created?