# Cannot access file inside Kubernetes cluster that has load balancer externally

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have the cluster setup below in AKS

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hpa-example
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hpa-example
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hpa-example
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hpa-example
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/hpa-example
        ports:
        - name: http-port
          containerPort: 80
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 200m
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hpa-example
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 31001
    nodePort: 31001
    targetPort: http-port
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: hpa-example
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: autoscaling/v1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: hpa-example-autoscaler
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: hpa-example
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
  targetCPUUtilizationPercentage: 50
```

The idea of this is to check AutoScaling

I need to have this available externally so I added

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: load-balancer-autoscaler
spec:
  selector:
    app: hpa-example
  ports:
    - port: 31001
      targetPort: 31001
  type: LoadBalancer
```

This now gives me an external IP however, I cannot connect to it in Postman or via a browser

What have I missed?

I have tried to change the ports between 80 and 31001 but that makes no difference

Comment: What's the exact URL you're trying to connect to?  What error do you get?  (On the `load-balancer-autoscaler` service, the `targetPort` needs to match the name or number of a `ports:` in the pod, or you could just change the `hpa-example` service to `type: LoadBalancer`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As posted by user @David Maze:

> What's the exact URL you're trying to connect to? What error do you get? (On the load-balancer-autoscaler service, the targetPort needs to match the name or number of a ports: in the pod, or you could just change the hpa-example service to type: LoadBalancer.)

I reproduced your scenario and found out issue in your configuration that could deny your ability to connect to this `Deployment`.

From the perspective of `Deployment` and `Service` of type `NodePort` everything seems to work okay.

If it comes to the `Service` of type `LoadBalancer` on the other hand:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: load-balancer-autoscaler
spec:
  selector:
    app: hpa-example
  ports:
    - port: 31001
      targetPort: 31001 # <--- CULPRIT
  type: LoadBalancer
```

This definition will send your traffic directly to the pods on port **`31001`** and **it should send it to the port `80`** (this is the port your app is responding on). You can change it either by:

- `targetPort: 80`
- `targetPort: http-port`

> You could also change the `Service` of the `NodePort` (`hpa-example`) to `LoadBalancer` as pointed by user @David Maze!

After changing this definition you will be able to run:

`$ kubectl get service`

```sh
NAME                       TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)           AGE
load-balancer-autoscaler   LoadBalancer   10.4.32.146   AA.BB.CC.DD     31001:31497/TCP   9m41s
```

- `curl AA.BB.CC.DD:31001` and get the reply of `OK!`

---

I encourage you to look on the additional resources regarding Kubernetes services:

- *[Docs.microsoft.com: AKS: Network: Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-network#services)*
- *[Stackoverflow.com: Questions: Difference between nodePort and LoadBalancer service types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509439/whats-the-difference-between-clusterip-nodeport-and-loadbalancer-service-types)*
- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)*