# Understanding access to NodePort from outside environment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I was reading k8s docs at https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/.

> NodePort: Exposes the Service on each Node's IP at a static port (the
> NodePort). A ClusterIP Service, to which the NodePort Service routes,
> is automatically created. **You'll be able to contact the NodePort
> Service, from outside the cluster, by requesting <NodeIP>:<NodePort>.**

So, I tried checking it practically. In this LoadBalancer service, port 31724 is a NodePort and 80 is the container port. According to docs, the NodePort should be open to the outer world and the container port should not. But with nmap, I found the reverse being true.

```
NAME      TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP               PORT(S)                  AGE
gen       LoadBalancer   10.200.32.132   10.44.9.162,10.44.9.163   80:31724/TCP,443:30039   20d
```

```
$ nmap -p 80 10.44.9.162

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2021-04-08 12:33 UTC
mass_dns: warning: Unable to determine any DNS servers. Reverse DNS is disabled. Try using --system-dns or specify valid servers with --dns-servers
Nmap scan report for 10.44.9.162
Host is up (0.00061s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.02 seconds

$ nmap -p 31724 10.44.9.162

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2021-04-08 12:33 UTC
mass_dns: warning: Unable to determine any DNS servers. Reverse DNS is disabled. Try using --system-dns or specify valid servers with --dns-servers
Nmap scan report for 10.44.9.162
Host is up (0.00044s latency).
PORT      STATE  SERVICE
31724/tcp closed unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.03 seconds
```

I am surely missing something. Please help me understand this. Thanks!

---

**Follow-up**:
I know follow-up should be a different question but it seemed like the correct place.
I created a NodePort service and retried the same. And it was as told in the description.

```
object-controller-np      NodePort       10.200.32.240   <none>         7203:31206/TCP                                             5s
```

NodeIP

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
inet 10.46.104.20 ...
```

```
$ nmap -p 7203 10.46.104.20

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2021-04-09 07:01 UTC
mass_dns: warning: Unable to determine any DNS servers. Reverse DNS is disabled. Try using --system-dns or specify valid servers with --dns-servers
Nmap scan report for 10.46.104.20
Host is up (0.00052s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
7203/tcp closed unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.03 seconds

$ nmap -p 31206 10.46.104.20

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2021-04-09 07:01 UTC
mass_dns: warning: Unable to determine any DNS servers. Reverse DNS is disabled. Try using --system-dns or specify valid servers with --dns-servers
Nmap scan report for 10.46.104.20
Host is up (0.00050s latency).
PORT      STATE SERVICE
31206/tcp open  unknown
```

Earlier I tried with LoadBalancer, as I thought it is kind of a superset of NodePort.
**Question**: So why the exact opposite behaviour with NodePort in NodePort-type service and LoadBalancer-type service.
From a [popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41510604/6740589):

> NodePort
> If you access this service on a nodePort from the node's external IP,
> it will route the request to `spec.clusterIp:spec.ports[*].port`, which
> will in turn route it to your `spec.ports[*].targetPort`, if set. This
> service can also be accessed in the same way as ClusterIP.
> ...
> LoadBalancer
> You can access this service from your load balancer's IP address,
> which routes your request to a nodePort, which in turn routes the
> request to the clusterIP port.

So, for a NodePort, the request goes like:

```
NodeIP:NodePort -> ClusterIP:Port -> ClusterIP:TargetPort
```

Above `Port` is the port specified as `port` in yaml that exposes the Kubernetes service on the specified port within the cluster. And TargetPort is the port specified by `targetPort` in yaml on which the service will send requests to, that your pod will be listening on.

For a LoadBalancer, the behaviour I expected was:

```
ExternalLBIP:NodePort --(load-balanced across nodes)--> NodeIP:NodePort -> ClusterIP:Port -> ClusterIP:TargetPort
```

What I see is:

```
ExternalLBIP:NodePort -> (doesn't work)
```

And instead, what works is:

```
ExternalLBIP:Port --(load-balanced across nodes)--> NodeIP:Port -> ClusterIP:Port -> ClusterIP:TargetPort
```

Comment: `NodePort` and `LoadBalancer` are two different `Service` types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is right because the IP you're hitting with `nmap` is the IP of the `LoadBalancer` created by the service of type `LoadBalancer`, which is meant to be open at 80 (and/or 443). While `NodePort` is accessible on the IP of the worker node on which the pod and the service are running.

The service you've deployed here is of type `LoadBalancer` and not `NodePort`.

For further read, check [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/) out.

**Answer to the follow up question**:

What you mentioned in what you expect and what actually works, both are incorrect.

`ExternalLBIP:NodePort` : If you look at the post you shared, `<NodePort>` is accessible via `<NodeIP>` and not with External IP of the LB.

`ExternalLBIP:Port --(load-balanced across nodes)--> NodeIP:Port ->` :  LB routes requests to a NodePort, so it will be `NodeIP:NodePort`.

So as to your question, the behaviour with `NodePort` in NodePort-type service and LoadBalancer-type service is not opposite. You just need to remember `NodePort` is to be accessed only on `NodeIP`.

In service type `NodePort`:

`NodeIP:NodePort -> ClusterIP:Port -> Pod:TargetPort`

In service type `LoadBalancer`:

`ExternalIPofLB:Port -> NodeIP:NodePort -> ClusterIP:Port -> Pod:TargetPort`

Eg. from a running service of type `LoadBalancer`:

```
kubectl get svc -n <namespace> <service-name>
NAME                       TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP                                                               PORT(S)          AGE
<service-name>-**********   LoadBalancer   172.20.96.130   a4b63c833c2***************d4-1996967498.<region>.elb.amazonaws.com   8443:31010/TCP   8m49s
```

As you can see in the below snippet, request will be forwarded from `LB Port to NodePort`.

[image: Listener of the ELB]

Comment: This was helpful. Can you please check the follow-up question?

Comment: Just so I am clear, the port for ExternalIP is `Port`, right?
`ExternalIP of LB:Port -> NodeIP:NodePort -> ClusterIP:Port -> Pod:TargetPort`

Comment: @subtleseeker yes that's right. I have added some info.