# Kubernetes service not exposed on minikube

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, minikube

I'm new to k8 and i'm trying to figure out how to deploy my first docker image on minikube.

My k8.yaml file is:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1

kind: Deployment

metadata:
  name: my-deployment
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-docker-image
        image: my-docker-image:1.0
        ports:
         - containerPort: 8080


---
apiVersion: v1

kind: Service

metadata:
  name: my-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: my-service
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
    
     
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: my-ingress
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-service
            port:
              number: 8080
```

Everything seems fine to me, however, I'm not able to reach my service on cluster.
I tried to create a tunnel using the `minikube tunnel` command and i have this result if i execute `kubectl get services`

```
NAME        TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
my-service  LoadBalancer   10.109.154.236   127.0.0.1     8080:30558/TCP   2m53s
```

However, if i try to call my service at 127.0.0.1:30588 host is unreachable.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue in the service selector as well, so first, we need to fix this service selector and it should match with with deployment label

```
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
```

and the service should refer to this `selector`

the selector should be `my-app` in the service or same as above for deployment

```
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: my-app
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
```

to access from the host

```
minikube service my-service
```

[image]

and here you go

```
kubectl delete -f myapp.yaml
kubectl apply -f myapp.yaml
```

deployment manifest

```
apiVersion: apps/v1

kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-docker-image
        image: nginx
        ports:
         - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app:  my-app
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

Also worth considering the service type for Minikube.

[What's the difference between ClusterIP, NodePort and LoadBalancer service types in Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509439/whats-the-difference-between-clusterip-nodeport-and-loadbalancer-service-types)