# Helm tells pods are installed and running, but... Where are my pods, that in fact aren't working?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to learn Helm with the help of a book, through a *minikube* instance.

This one says: after having declared some charts repository, just install *Drupal*, for example, with the command:

```bash
helm install mysite bitnami/drupal
```

that will soon respond that it is ready (what it does),
and that it is ready to be joined on `http://drupal.local/`,
and this doesn't work at all, the web site isn't found.

I wonder what's happening, and type a command:

```bash
sudo kubectl get pods
```

and see this:

```
NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS        AGE    IP           NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
mysite-drupal-d6d99c65f-lvtxf   1/1     Running   2 (2d17h ago)   6d8h   172.17.0.5   minikube   <none>           <none>
mysite-mariadb-0                1/1     Running   2 (2d17h ago)   6d8h   172.17.0.2   minikube   <none>           <none>
```

And I would like to understand what can trouble my installation if the book says it should work like a charm.

But when I do a:

```bash
sudo docker ps
```

I'm receiving an empty list of active containers. (stopped ones aren't related to Drupal or Kubernetes)

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS      PORTS                                         NAMES
```

Where are my pods? The ones that helm/kubernetes say that they are running?

I'd like to investigate their logs, for instance.

---

I've found the drupal's logs by a

```bash
kubectl logs mysite-drupal-d6d99c65f-lvtxf --all-containers
```

and it doesn't look really unhappy,

```
drupal 12:37:14.77 
drupal 12:37:14.77 Welcome to the Bitnami drupal container
drupal 12:37:14.77 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/containers
drupal 12:37:14.77 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/containers/issues
drupal 12:37:14.77 
drupal 12:37:14.77 INFO  ==> ** Starting Drupal setup **
realpath: /bitnami/apache/conf: No such file or directory
drupal 12:37:14.79 INFO  ==> Configuring the HTTP port
drupal 12:37:14.79 INFO  ==> Configuring the HTTPS port
drupal 12:37:14.79 INFO  ==> Configuring Apache ServerTokens directive
drupal 12:37:14.80 INFO  ==> Configuring PHP options
drupal 12:37:14.80 INFO  ==> Setting PHP expose_php option
drupal 12:37:14.81 INFO  ==> Validating settings in MYSQL_CLIENT_* env vars
drupal 12:37:14.83 WARN  ==> You set the environment variable ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes. For safety reasons, do not use this flag in a production environment.
drupal 12:37:14.86 INFO  ==> Restoring persisted Drupal installation
drupal 12:37:14.90 INFO  ==> Trying to connect to the database server

drupal 12:37:55.95 INFO  ==> ** Drupal setup finished! **
drupal 12:37:55.96 INFO  ==> ** Starting Apache **
[Thu Sep 01 12:37:56.024007 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 1] AH01909: www.example.com:8443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Sep 01 12:37:56.024617 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 1] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Sep 01 12:37:56.040330 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 1] AH01909: www.example.com:8443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Sep 01 12:37:56.040483 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 1] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Sep 01 12:37:56.049575 2022] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.54 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1n configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Sep 01 12:37:56.049597 2022] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: '/opt/bitnami/apache/bin/httpd -f /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/httpd.conf -D FOREGROUND'
172.17.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2022:12:37:56 +0000] "GET /user/login HTTP/1.1" 200 17473
172.17.0.1 - - [01/Sep/2022:12:38:01 +0000] "GET /user/login HTTP/1.1" 200 17473
```

but it doesn't give me a clue about where my underlying containers, installation of *MariaDB* Drupal uses, physically are, if they aren't on *Docker*, which I believed, was the default choice of Kubernetes/Helm.

Comment: perhaps your kubernetes is not configured to use docker as container runtime.

Comment: @TheFool Thanks. But then, what will it use instead, by default? Because kubernetes says it knows these pods installed and running: I deduct it installed drupal component somewhere... But where?

Comment: Now using `crictl` is encouraged for these kind of operations. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-cluster/crictl/#:~:text=crictl%20is%20a%20command%2Dline,in%20the%20cri%2Dtools%20repository.

Comment: @P.... But I don't have it. A `crictl` or `sudo crictl` responds _command not found_.

Comment: The Kubernetes application is running in a possibly-remote cluster; you shouldn't expect to be able to use `docker` or similar commands to interact with the containers directly.  You'll need to somehow make your application accessible from outside the cluster; [What's the difference between ClusterIP, NodePort and LoadBalancer service types in Kubernetes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509439/whats-the-difference-between-clusterip-nodeport-and-loadbalancer-service-types) could be a good starting point.

Comment: @MarcLeBihan the command needs to be installed on the node where POD is scheduled.

Comment: Where is your Kubernetes Cluster ?

Comment: If you are using minikube, then you will not see containers on your laptop. You will find containers inside the minikube vm. Do `minikube ssh` to login into it.

Comment: is your cluster running?. If minikube is up and running, it should be listed as a container under docker ps. Also, did helm install fail?

Comment: @JasonY Sorry I wasn't able to check these days. I hope this week.