# Exposing pod to outside world with MySQL database in Azure Kubernetes Service

Tags: mysql, azure, kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-service

Hi I've deployed single MySQL db instance in Azure via the YAML file in Azure Kubernetes service. I can get into the container via CLI when I'm inside my cluster. I would like to connect with db instance via external client like MySQL Workbench or Sqlelectron or others, outside the cluster. As I found out it's possible via correctly exposing DB instance by Service configuration.

My deployment of single instance MySQL DB instance is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: mysql-db-testing-service
    namespace: testing
spec:
    type: ClusterIP
    ports:
    - port: 3306
      #targetPort: 3306
    selector:
        app: mysql-db-testing
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: mysql-db-testing
    namespace: testing
spec:
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: mysql-db-testing
    replicas: 1
    strategy:
        type: Recreate
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: mysql-db-testing
        spec:
            containers: 
            - name: mysql-db-container-testing 
              image: mysql:8.0.31
              env: 
              - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
                value: test12345
              ports:
              - containerPort: 3306
                name: mysql-port
              volumeMounts:
              - mountPath: "/var/lib/mysql"
                name: mysql-persistent-storage
            volumes:
            - name: mysql-persistent-storage
              persistentVolumeClaim:
                claimName: azure-managed-disk-pvc-mysql-testing
            nodeSelector:
                env: preprod
```

As I've mentioned I can get to the container via CLI:

[image]

Console output regarding the working pod with db looks like:
[image]

Console output regarding the service:

[image: v]

Is there something missing in my deployment YAML file or maybe there are missing some fields? How can I expose db to the outside world? I would be grateful for help.

Comment: hi, krzysztof please feel free to update the status of the question if any of the below answer resolve your issue or do an upvote if found it helpful. don't hesitate to share your answer too if any.

Answer (score 1):

You are using ClusterIP service(line 7). The kubernetes ClusterIP service is not made to allow you to access a pod outside of the cluster. ClusterIP just provide a way to have a not changing IP for other internal services to access your pod.
You should use instead Loadbalanacer.
Cf https://stackoverflow.com/a/48281728/8398523 for differences

Answer (score 1):

You have used the **type: ClusterIP** so it won't expose the MYSQL outside the cluster ideally, your Microservices running in the cluster will be able to access it however you can not use it externally.

To expose the service we generally have to use the **type: LoadBalancer**. It will directly expose your **MySQL** service internet and from your **local** **workbench**, you can connect to **DB** running on K8s.

If you really don't want to expose the MySQL service directly to internet you can deploy the **adminer**.

So traffic will flow like

```
internet > adminer > internal communication > MySQL service > MySQL POD
```

YAML file to deploy and get the UI output directly in the browser, it will ask of **MySQL** DB **username**, **password**, Host (mysql-db-testing-service.testing.svc.cluster.local) to connect

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: adminer
  labels:
    app: adminer
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: adminer
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: adminer
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: adminer
          image: adminer:4.6.3
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: ADMINER_DESIGN
              value: "pappu687"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: adminer-svc
spec:
  type: ClusterIP(Internally to cluster)/LoadBalancer (Expose to internet)
  selector:
    app: adminer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
```

Port-forward for local access or use service `type: LoadBalancer`

```
kubectl port-forward svc/adminer-svc 8080:8080
```

Open `localhost:8080` in browser

Comment: Harsh - Does it mean I can use CLUSTER-IP  as a hostname and port 3306 to connection by java Spring app which is also inside the cluster as separate pod don't I?

Comment: Yes right you can use cluster ip host name internally best practice suggest that