Kubernetes curl clusterIP timeout
I am new to K8. I have deployed an nginx service as bellow
kubectl describe svc nginx-nfs-service 

Name:              nginx-nfs-service
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=nginx
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.105.179.135
IPs:               10.105.179.135
Port:              <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:        80/TCP
Endpoints:         172.16.222.234:80
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>

Here is the pod that runs the service
kubectl describe pod nginx-nfs-deployment-5dd946cdd6-7hh4k 

Name:             nginx-nfs-deployment-5dd946cdd6-7hh4k
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             c1-node1/192.168.0.11
Start Time:       Mon, 12 Aug 2024 07:45:11 +0200
Labels:           app=nginx
                  pod-template-hash=5dd946cdd6
Annotations:      cni.projectcalico.org/containerID: 7a0f4c8666f1d5f30050560bb5c7ef4bc5c738cbbcdb81055283b0906862f5df
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 172.16.222.234/32
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 172.16.222.234/32
Status:           Running
IP:               172.16.222.234
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/nginx-nfs-deployment-5dd946cdd6
Containers:
  nginx:
    Container ID:   containerd://cc35872a49e107a113439459f362f1cd0ac9bc6f3b7e328f255a48fe295bbfa8
    Image:          nginx
    Image ID:       docker.io/library/nginx@sha256:6af79ae5de407283dcea8b00d5c37ace95441fd58a8b1d2aa1ed93f5511bb18c
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Mon, 12 Aug 2024 07:45:15 +0200
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none> ....

On the control plane node, I try to do
curl http://10.105.179.135

but it times out. I need help to resolve this. I can ping the node that hosts the service from the control plane.

At least I see that nginx pod uses port 80, but you want to use https (port 443). There is no automatic redirection unless you set it up.
So, if you need to use https and port 443, you can set up ingress rule use a certificate for TLS.

sorry it was actually http. edited

I think you need to use NodePort service type for your service if you want to reach it from outside. ClusterIP service type uses internal IP address range which is available for internal communication. For example, between pod. If you connect to a pod with curl and use your curl command you will be able to get that address.
You can have a look at this post about the differences between ClusterIP and NodePort services: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509439/difference-between-clusterip-nodeport-and-loadbalancer-service-types-in-kuberne

I intend to access the services from within the cluster only
